# Configure multiple php sites under single server without domain using NGINX

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I have a VPS but I'm working without a domain yet, the server is currently using NGINX which I'm really new to.

I'm developing 2 different sites, they will be hosted on that same VPS but they must be accessed using diferent urls ('12.34.56.78/siteA' and '12.34.56.78/siteB').

They will eventually be given different real domains, but meanwhile they have to be served under the VPS' IP. I can't access them using the configured extension (siteA, siteB), and IP alone seems to serve just one of them, on the wrong url, by the way.

### HOW DO I SETUP THIS UP, or else WHAT IS THE RIGHT WAY TO MAKE THIS BOTH SITES WORK?

Current config and errors below:

### SITES DEMO CONTENT

```
$ sudo ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
siteA  siteB


$ sudo cat /var/www/html/siteA/index.php
this is SITE A at /var/www/html/siteA/index.php

$ sudo cat /var/www/html/siteB/index.php
this is SITE B at /var/www/html/siteB/index.php
```

### SITE A NGINX CONFIG

```
$ sudo cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/siteA

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name 12.34.56.78;      
  root /var/www/html/siteA;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  location /siteA {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /siteA/index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

### SITE B NGINX CONFIG

EXACT SAME BUT WITH SITEB

```
# EXACT SAME BUT WITH SITEB
$ sudo cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/siteB

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name 12.34.56.78;      
  root /var/www/html/siteB;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  location /siteB {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /siteB/index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

### APPLY CONFIG

```
$ sudo nginx -t && sudo service nginx reload && sudo service nginx restart
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "12.34.56.78" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "12.34.56.78" on [::]:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

#RESET LOG
$ echo "" | sudo tee /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

### TEST AND ERRORS

```
$ curl http://12.34.56.78/siteA
404 Not Found

$ curl http://12.34.56.78/siteB
404 Not Found

$ curl http://12.34.56.78
this is SITE A at /var/www/html/siteA/index.php


$ tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
2023/12/30 22:50:17 [error] 119546#119546: *2 open() "/var/www/html/siteA/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 12.34.56.78, server: 12.34.56.78, request: "GET /test HTTP/1.1", host: "12.34.56.78"
```

Comment: I don’t have an answer for you, but treating “paths” as if they were “sites” is asking for trouble. If you are just dev’ing local, use a hosts file. If you need public users to get to them, either buy a domain or use a dynamic DNS service to get a free one. Nginx considers a “site” to generally be the host or IP, and you are just going to be fighting the system if you pretend otherwise, and when you eventually get the domains, you will fight undoing things.

Comment: You want to create a single server to serve two apps in folders. You have defined **two** servers with identical names (see the warnings) and Nginx can only use the first one. Put both locations into the **same** server block.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set them up as two subdirs on the same IP-based site (i.e., `12.34.56.78/siteA` and `12.34.56.78/siteB`) -- that will just lead to headache and (almost certainly) security issues. Rather, set them up as separate name-based sites, just like you have in your example, as you would if your DNS were working, and then use local DNS/hostname overrides.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sitea;
    root /path/to/site/a/public;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name siteb;
    root /path/to/site/b/public;
}
```

> I can't access them using the configured extension (siteA, siteB),

Sure you can. You just need to override the DNS service on the machine you're browsing from. Simply edit the `/etc/hosts` file on Linux or the `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` file on Windows and add the line:

```
12.34.56.78 sitea siteb
```

Or you could do it as two separate lines:

```
12.34.56.78 sitea
12.34.56.78 siteb
```

Then you can browse `http://sitea` or `http://siteb` on that machine, and you'll be directed to the correct site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Alex, I just applied it. :-)    AFAIU, this would let me browse that URL on the local machine (the VPS).   I need to share the progress with the customer. I just tried to reach the url from another machine and it got a 404

Comment: Any machine that you want to have access to the sites would have to be updated. So, the other machine on your LAN, and the customer's machine(s) would have to have the hosts file edited. However, if you're at the point where you're sharing with the customer, then you're better off just using real DNS. Even if it's not the final correct customer-provided name, at least assign it a temporary (but live) third level name on your own domain like like sitea.yourdomain.com.